# Core Data Objective-C Exception on Context Save in SwiftUI App

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

When I do a fresh install of a SwiftUI app on an iOS device, I get an exception when Core Data first attempts a save.

My app delegate makes a call to a function that has this CloudKit call:

```
iCloud.container.fetchUserRecordID(){ recordID, error in
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let recordID = recordID{
      let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
      //...

      do{
        try context.save() //<-- <!!!> Thread 1: hit Objective-C exception <!!!>
      }catch{
        print("fetchiCloudUserId CD Error")
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only other information I have about the crash is here in Xcode:

[image]

My guess is that somehow Core Data isn't ready yet. My `PersistenceController` looks like this:

```
struct PersistenceController {
  static let shared = PersistenceController()
  let container: NSPersistentContainer

  init(){
    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Avid")
    
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { storeDescription, error in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        print("=========\nUnresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

After I rebuild my app again on the device, the exception doesn't occur. Any ideas?

Comment: Though it shouldnt make much difference, as you are already accessing `viewContext` in main queue (ViewContext is backed by main queue anyway) try using `perform` or `performAndWait` on context and avoid using manual thread context switch (.`DispatchQueue.main.async`)  Can you also print the error, data provided isnt sufficient to dig further

Comment: There is no error to print since it doesn’t catch. It just says `Thread 1: hit Objective-C exception` and hangs.

Comment: Thats strange :| Can you try catching the objective-C exception instead, swift try catch doesnt actually catch / handle exception it handles only error :) If you need to know how to catch objective-C exception in swift try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346312/crash-detect-swift/66346989#66346989 I would rather try to execute `context.save()` in objective-c block and see if I can catch any exception that might be able to give better idea of whats happening

Comment: "somehow Core Data isn't ready" - yes, initially setting up CoreData takes some time. You need to ensure, that you use CoreData only after initialisation is finished. The solution may look cumbersome though: use a dispatch queue, initially suspended, where you execute _all_ CoreData calls. Resume it in the completion handler which tells you that CoreData is ready. Or use some dirty tricks where your first usage of CoreData waits for a certain time - ugly, but...  ;)

Answer (score 1):

A big thanks to @CouchDeveloper for getting me on the right track. I didn't know I could make Xcode divulge more about such a vague exception. I talked to another developer and learned I could set a symbolic breakpoint that will tell me why it crashed. Here's what I did.

Create a new **Symbolic Breakpoint** in the Breakpoint navigator (one of the left column tabs in Xcode).

**Symbol:** `objc_exception_throw`

**Condition**:

```
(BOOL)[(NSString *)[[(id)$arg1 class] className] isEqualToString:@"_NSCoreDataOptimisticLockingException"] == 0
```

**Action**: `Debugger Command`

```
po $arg1
```

[image]

After setting that up, the console showed me I had a constraint conflict on a unique field I was setting. I was able to take action on that and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When it turns out your issue stems from some data race issue, where CoreData is simply not yet ready to execute requests, you may use this solution:

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    private let _container: NSPersistentContainer
    private let sem = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    var container: NSPersistentContainer {
        get {
            sem.wait()
            sem.signal()
            return _container
        }
    }
    init() {
      _container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Avid")
      let sem = self.sem
      _container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { storeDescription, error in
        sem.signal()
        if let error = error as NSError? {
          print("=========\nUnresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
      })
    }
}
```

What it does is, it uses a semaphore which is initially not satisfied, to wait synchronously for the underlying `NSPersistentContainer` value to become valid.

Note: when you read `synchronously` - you should immediately become sceptical about the usefulness of the solution!

The semaphore will be signaled in the completion handler and thus enables subsequent accesses to the `NSPersistentContainer` value.

There are however big caveats with this approach:

- it doesn't look pretty (also a sign that something is not right)
- synchronous waits are prone to dead locks
- you get a crash anyway, when your CoreData cannot be initialised
- it blocks whatever thread is calling the `container` property.

The pros are: it's light weight and easy to implement and easy to understand.
Note, we really need this only once when the app is initially launched. Then, we would not need all this stuff.

A better solution IMHO is to use a queue as described in my comment. Still, not ideal - adds a lot overhead with switching queues.

Yet another approach may use Swift Combine, which returns some Publisher where you execute your CoreData calls. This is certainly the best approach regarding robustness and the opportunities you obtain to handle errors, but also quite elaborate and adds a lot overhead which is really only once required after we launch the app for the first time.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this. I tried the semaphore approach you suggested, but the same crash occurs. It seems that Core Data is, in fact, ready. It's just not ready to save a context yet. I tried a fetch request right before the crash point and it works fine. 

Comment: Too bad ;) To get a clue what's going on, we would need a detailed crash report. Can you find any other additional information in the crash report? At least full backtrace. Also, enable CoreData Debugging, Thread-Sanitizer